# Get category ID from order item inside woocommerce hook

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

In `functions.php` we have:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'mysite_processing', 10, 1);
```

then inside this function we get order items:

```
function mysite_processing($order_id) {
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $items = $order->get_items();
    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        $product_id = $item->get_product_id();
    }
}
```

After getting the product id, we want to get the category id that product belongs. We already try with get_the_terms and has_term functions, both didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Solved, added to items for: $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
function mysite_processing($order_id) {
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $items = $order->get_items();
    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        $product_id = $item->get_product_id();
        $term_list = wp_get_post_terms($product_id,'product_cat',array('fields'=>'ids'));
        print_r($term_list);
        $cat_id = (int) $term_list[0];
        echo $cat_id;
        die();
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working, dump of $term_list: Array<br /> (<br /> )<br />

Comment: What you get in the print_r($term_list)

Comment: this: Array<br /> (<br /> )<br />

Comment: If we can check if product type is virtual our idea will work too, but this data is not coming with order item

Comment: I just ched my code and i checked that while changing the order status it is showing me the correct data

Comment: Please check in your answer if some bracket is missing

Comment: please check now

Comment: still not working. Maybe on your functions you have added in begin some code to make wp_get_post_terms work?

Comment: It is the global one it is nothing which i created custom by my self